# Calculate rolling average and use for missing values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to build a model in PowerBI that forecasts future values based certain inputs. The issue I am running into is that some of my data is missing rows, and I also need to use the last value of data as the one for the next period, to which I will add additional (calculated) values. I used an index that starts at -5 and goes through 30, and added a date column expressed as Today()+Index. The data looks like this:

```
Index |  Date Index |  Values |
------------------------------
 -6        11/4       2     
 -5        11/5       5
 -4        11/6       7  
 -3        11/7      
 -2        11/8       5
 -1        11/9       4
  0        11/10        <-- This is today
  1        11/11
  2        11/12
 ...
```

What I need the data to look like is this:

```
   Index |  Date Index |  Values |
------------------------------
   -6        11/4       2     
   -5        11/5       5
   -4        11/6       7  
   -3        11/7       4.667
   -2        11/8       5
   -1        11/9       4
    0        11/10      4  <-- This is today
    1        11/11      4
    2        11/12      4
    ...
```

The Dax Formula I have is:

```
 Values = 
       If(
          AND(
              SUMX(
                   Filter(
              Table 2,Table 2[Date]='Summary Table'[Date Index]
                          ),
                   Table 2[Initial Values]
                   )=0,
              'Summary Table'[Date Index]<Today()
               ),
               Calculate(
                         Averagex(
                                  Table 2,Table 2[Initial Values]
                                  ),
                         DATESINPERIOD(
                                       Table 2[Date],Today()-1,5,DAY
                                       )
                         ),
               SUMX(
                    Filter(
                           Table 2,Table 2[Date]='Summary Table'[Date Index]
                           ),
                    Table 2[Initial Values]
                    )
            )
```

Note that I am pulling in my values from a different table, Table 2, which has multiple dates with values, which I am summing in this summary table by date. For some reason, the formula is filling in an incorrect average value for missing values, and not pulling the last value (from Today()-1) through to the end of the data. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried to format your dax forumula, using daxformatter.com, but it gave error and I had to add single quotes around Table 2 name. I put the formatted version on pastebin. You might check it for correctness and then edit your post to replace the DAX formula to make your question more understandable. 
https://pastebin.com/V9vgSpYy

Comment: Hi @sergiom, thanks for the advice. I formatted the DAX code to make it a bit more readable. The function works in my query, but as stated, it returns the wrong average number, and doesn't pull down values.